# Trying Gradle build - "Task 'build' not found in root project"

Tags: gradle

I just started reading "Pro Spring MVC with web flow" and it comes with a code sample that I want to follow.

- **What I want** - I want to build the applications as it's done in the book, using `Gradle`
- **What is the problem** - I have never used `Gradle` before and when I try to execute what I'm thinking I have to I get this error `Task 'build' not found in root project`
- **What have I done so far** - Yesterday I downloaded `Gradle` from the official site and get it to work. Today when I actually tried to execute the steps from the book it turns out that the sample code comes with its own Gradle distribution and I executed it which I think followed to getting a second distribution of Gradle. However, I don't know if this may be a problem or not. now my directory with the sample code looks like this:
  [image]

Then it's written that I have to execute `../gradlew build` which I execute like this and get the following:
[image]

- **What have I tried** - The only thing that came to my mind was to leave only the Gradle's stuff plus the `appendixA-bookstore` folder in case Gradle recognize all directories as different builds but no success.
- **What's the final result that I want to accomplish** - First I want to figure out where is my mistake and how to build the sample application(s). And also it would be perfect if I actually can do this from my first `Gradle` setup which as I wrote did yesterday and what exactly should I do to use this sample code with my fresh and original Gradle setup?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You didn't do what you're being asked to do.

What is asked:

> I have to execute ../gradlew build

What you do

```
cd ..
gradlew build
```

That's not the same thing.

The first one will use the gradlew command found in the `..` directory (`mdeinum...`), and look for the build file to execute in the current directory, which is (for example) `chapter1-bookstore`.

The second one will execute the gradlew command found in the current directory (`mdeinum...`), and look for the build file to execute in the current directory, which is `mdeinum...`.

So the build file executed is not the same.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you suggesting me to do. The sample code comes in a `Zip` file which contains all the directories on the printscreen plus the `gradlew` batch file which I executed. It just so happened that I unziped the directory on the desktop so my path is `C:\Users\Xman\Desktop\mdeinum-pro-spring-mvc-code-5d01f03` and I see that I obviously don't get the instructions right but what I have to change to make this work?

Comment: Tried `C:\Users\Xman\Desktop\mdeinum-pro-spring-mvc-code-5d01f03\appendixA-bookstore\..\gradlew build` and few other modifications but no success, could you be more specific on how exactly to execute this? Sorry for being so newb.

Answer (score 13):

run

```
gradle clean
```

then try

```
gradle build
```

it worked for me

Answer (score 6):

Check your file: `settings.gradle` for presence lines with included subprojects (for example:
include `chapter1-bookstore`
)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gradle 7.5.1 then you need to run the command as

```
$ gradle tasks <taskname>
```

So in your case the task name would be the one found under chapter folders.