# Import project source code developed in eclipse ADT into android studio without exporting

Tags: android, import, android-studio, project, adt

I am very novice to android studio, today only I set up android studio.

1. I developed an android project/app in eclipse ADT.
2. As Google now recommends android studio for android development,I set up android studio today. But before that I deleted all eclipse ADT installation stuff.
3. Now I wants to import all the source code which I had written in eclipse ADT.
4. According to [official docs](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html) I have to locate project **exported from Eclipse.**
5. As I dont have eclipse at all how  can I export it?

Is there any way to import only source code which was developed in Eclipse ADT?

Please share your solution, it will be great help!
Thanks.

***Edit : Solution***

I solved this situation:)
1) Directly imported source code of existing eclipse ADT project.
2) I got an error while build -> Make build 
 **"FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Task '' not found in root project 'MyProject'.
* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED"**

3) Also I got an error saying target version-19 not found. As My existing project defined target version 19 and my current sdk platform is 21. I got this error message.

4) I followed the answer given by Ankit Bansal in below link: [Android Studio build fails with "Task '' not found in root project 'MyProject'."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172006/android-studio-build-fails-with-task-not-found-in-root-project-myproject)

4) And my project build successfully and now I just ran on my real device.

Hope this will help to others!

Comment: Just import the project directly into Android Studio. That tends to work better than exporting from Eclipse anyway.

Comment: check [Migrating From Eclipse Projects](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects)

Comment: @ScottBarta, @ Xingchen I did it. And I got FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> failed to find target android-19 : /home/user/desktop/android-sdk-linux Though I deleted android:targetSDKVersion="19" from manifest file. Right now I am installing sdk platform 19. Hope it will solve my problem. Thanks.