# Android studio keeps not finding target android-19 but I don't want to compile with that

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to import a project in Android Studio that was initially meant to be compiled with Android-19 API. However now I need to make it work on a device with Android 4.0.3 (so I want to compile with android-15). Yet, Android Studio keeps telling me this, no matter what I do:

```
Error:failed to find target android-19 : C:\Users\BurrafatoMa\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
<a href="install.android.platform">Install missing platform(s) and sync project</a>
```

(Lucky me that I did not have android-19 installed, otherwise I would have never noticed, right?)

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion '17.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 15
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
...
```

project.properties:

```
target=android-15
```

I tried the solutions proposed in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25525390/1876359) and on [other sites](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2014/07/02/gradle-sdk-location-not-found-the-problem-and-solution/), with no success. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the project contains some module or library that needs android-19 to compile, I think

Comment: Seems correct! That is what I was just investigating in the meantime. In fact I found a referenced library that needs 19; yet after I changed it to require 15, it keeps giving me the same error (in the library). Looking for some other hidden dependences...

Comment: I just forgot do update this almost-year-old question of mine. Yes, the library was referencing another library and it needed android-19. Quite annoying that I needed to go hunting around for the hidden dependency, though.