# gradle is showing error when rebuild the app

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

hey hi I am new to android, when i am rebuilding my application getting an error, when i trying re-build the project. i am not understanding where the culprit is. I added a jar file to the android.

```
Error:16:12:04.890 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
16:12:04.891 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
16:12:04.891 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
16:12:04.891 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
16:12:04.891 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Task 'option' not found in root project 'Design'.
16:12:04.891 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
16:12:04.891 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
16:12:04.891 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. 
16:12:04.891 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
16:12:04.892 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
16:12:04.892 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.execution.TaskSelectionException: Task 'option' not found in root project 'Design'.
16:12:04.892 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:100)
16:12:04.892 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:75)
16:12:04.892 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.commandline.CommandLineTaskParser.parseTasks(CommandLineTaskParser.java:42)
16:12:04.892 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:44)
16:12:04.892 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:42)
16:12:04.893 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$100(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
16:12:04.893 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:48)
16:12:04.893 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
16:12:04.893 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:42)
16:12:04.893 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$100(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
16:12:04.893 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:48)
16:12:04.893 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:44)
16:12:04.893 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:42)
16:12:04.893 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.select(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:35)
16:12:04.893 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:142)
16:12:04.894 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
16:12:04.894 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
16:12:04.894 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
16:12:04.894 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:54)
16:12:04.894 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
16:12:04.894 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
16:12:04.894 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
16:12:04.894 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:49)
16:12:04.894 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
16:12:04.894 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
16:12:04.894 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
16:12:04.895 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
16:12:04.895 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
16:12:04.895 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
16:12:04.895 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
16:12:04.895 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
16:12:04.895 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
16:12:04.895 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
16:12:04.895 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
16:12:04.895 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
16:12:04.895 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
16:12:04.896 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
16:12:04.896 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
16:12:04.896 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
16:12:04.896 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
16:12:04.896 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
16:12:04.896 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
16:12:04.896 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
16:12:04.896 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
16:12:04.896 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
16:12:04.896 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
16:12:04.896 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
16:12:04.897 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
16:12:04.897 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
16:12:04.897 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
16:12:04.897 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
```

gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sun.suni.design"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/carousel-api-v1.jar')
}
```

gradle build:

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Can anybody help me to find the exact error

Answer (score 0):

**From:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/27522098

> Download system image(of targeted android level of your project) from
>   sdk manager for the project you have imported.
>
> This error comes when you do not have target sdk of your android
>   project installed in sdk folder
>
> for eg. Your imported project's target sdk level may be android-19 and
>   on sdk folder->system-images you may have android-21 installed. so you
>   have to download android-19 system image and other files from sdk
>   manager or you can copy paste it if you have the system image.

Comment: But i run previously it worked. I tried to add my app to github but it failed after that it showing the error like this

Comment: is there a parent build.gradle? what is the `root project 'Design'`? can you post that build.gradle?