# Task 'continue' not found in root project 'Demo2'

Tags: android, gradle

I built an android project, and when I ran it, there was the following problem. even if I created a new project in any directory, the problem also appeared. so what's going on here?

> BUILD FAILED in 0s
>   Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Task '–continue' not found in root project 'Demo2'.
> - Try:
>     Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace > option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get > 
>     more log output.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 0s

Comment: [Maybe it will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172006/android-studio-build-fails-with-task-not-found-in-root-project-myproject) Maybe it will help you

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This looks strange. The error seems to be the `–` character, which is not a double-dash `--` but rather what happens sometimes when a text editor transforms a double in a long one.

[`--continue` is not a task but a Gradle command line flag](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:continue_build_on_failure) used to tell a build to continue executing even after a task fails.

Without more context regarding the creation and exact steps to launch the build, it is impossible to say more as to why this happens in your case.