# Gradle - How to build 2 multimodule projects together? (or a module from other project)

Tags: java, gradle, composition, multi-module

How to build 2 multimodule projects together? (or a module from other project)

I came back to gradle after not using for couples of years
and wanted to compile more modules together
But those modules have own `settings.gradle`, so it looks like gradle considers them fully independent project that can't be mixed. At least I get error when I try.

The example project https://github.com/emeraldpay/polkaj

I add examples to be compiled together

```
// compiling 6 examples together with the polkaj library
include(':balance')
project(':balance').projectDir = file('./examples/balance')
include(':encoding')
project(':encoding').projectDir = file('./examples/encoding')
include(':keys')
project(':keys').projectDir = file('./examples/keys')
include(':rpc')
project(':rpc').projectDir = file('./examples/rpc')
include(':runtime-explorer')
project(':runtime-explorer').projectDir = file('./examples/runtime-explorer')
include(':types')
project(':types').projectDir = file('./examples/types')
```

But then get errors like

> Project 'MyProject' not found in root project 'MyProject'.

[Android: Project 'MyProject' not found in root project 'MyProject'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753798/android-project-myproject-not-found-in-root-project-myproject/69103012#69103012)

**How to build 2 multimodule projects together?** (or a module from other project)

Comment: This behavior (modules outside of the project directory) had been deprecated and will go away. Better make a build-pipeline with two steps, then you can let the one depend on the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for Composite Builds:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html

https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_composite_builds_basics.html