# Project 'react-native-reanimated' not found in root project

Tags: react-native, android-studio, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

In my react native project I don't have `"react-native-reanimated"` but when I rebuilt my project I got this error:
`"Project "react-native-reanimated" was not found in the root project`

So when I install ‍`react-native-reanimated‍` I get an `NDK` install error, but when I install the `ndk` and get the `apk` from the project, the app won't open and crashes.

So I uninstalled `react-native-reanimated` and `ndk` and `cmake` but again I got the error `"project 'react-native-reanimated' was not found in the root project"`

please help me

[Android Studio Error Message Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTPDo.png)

Comment: Possible gradle related issue - try out the solutions in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753798/android-project-myproject-not-found-in-root-project-myproject

Comment: Glad to help - just gonna leave an answer to try my luck for an accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible gradle related issue - try out the solutions in this post:
[Android: Project 'MyProject' not found in root project 'MyProject'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753798/android-project-myproject-not-found-in-root-project-myproject)

But basically, delete the `.gradle` folder in your project's root folder and resync gradle from Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

try to run below command

npm install --force react-native-reanimated

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps

it work for me

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me

```
cd android && ./gradlew --refresh-dependencies && cd ..
```