# Gradle Build failed: Task 'stacktrace' not found in root project

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I know this question is asked many times, and i used all the Answers to to resolve my error. Here is my problem.
I tried almost all Answer present on So, so please before mark my question as Duplicate, please read my question care, i mentioned all steps that are answered on SO Questions.

Whenever i tried to **run / build / clean project** i got error *** What went wrong:
Task 'stacktrace' not found in root project 'project'.**

Library and Sdk i m using 
ViewPagerIndicator - JakeWharton
Facebook SDK
PDK (Pinterest sdk)
gcm.jar
httpcore-4.4.4.jar

What i have tried so far

1. changed Gradle version from 2.2.1-all.zip to lower version
2. changes Gradle Build version
3. delete all Library and run
4. All library project minSdkVersion same (my project using minSdkVersion: 11 )
5. clean project and Rebuild
6. Invalidate cache and restart Android Studio
7. delete .idea and .gradle folder then Import project
8. Created new project and copy paste old Project into project but it also gives same error on build
9. deleted .gradle folder from user folder(i m using windows 7 )
10. try to build project using command line
11. Changed JDK version new jdk1.8.0_73 ( my project was build on jdk1.7.0_55 ) [here is thread that said using new JDK version will resolve problem](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76360)
12. here are Answers i follwed [**first solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172006/android-studio-build-fails-with-task-not-found-in-root-project-myproject) , **[Second solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753798/android-project-myproject-not-found-in-root-project-myproject)**, [third solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093024/trying-gradle-build-task-build-not-found-in-root-project)   [Fourth Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172006/android-studio-build-fails-with-task-not-found-in-root-project-myproject) and many more.

Temporary solution(it was working before but not now )
i have backup of project two week ago, i import that backup project and replace the files and it works 
But when i do clean project error came again

here is app level build.gradle file

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XXX"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile project(':library')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.8.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.4.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

}
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Here is proejct level builld.gradle file

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'


    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Help will be Appreciated!. Please share your ideas to resolve this error 
i m trying to deal with error from 1 week and i  m not getting answer from anywhere that will work for me

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172006/android-studio-build-fails-with-task-not-found-in-root-project-myproject

Comment: yes , i m having same error , but i used the solution gave on that question, please read, i mentioned 5 steps that is present on Answers of question that gave link. @NguyenDoanTung