# Task 'helloworld' not found in root project while running gradle task

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

getting below error while running from command prompt as gradle helloWorld

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'helloWorld' not found in root project 'sample'.
- Try:
  Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option
  to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output
  .

BUILD FAILED

Below is my build.gradle file :
task helloWorld << {
  println 'hello, world'
}

Also I am running the command from the same directory where build.gradle file exists

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093024/trying-gradle-build-task-build-not-found-in-root-project

Comment: I have already gone through above link but when I execute ../gradlew build getting not recognized command